# can't access a place in memory

Tags: c, file, fread

I'm trying to read a binary file of 32 bytes in C, however I'm keep getting "segmentation fault (code dumped)" when I run my program, 
it would be great if somebody can help me out by pointing where did I go wrong?.
my code is here below:

```
int main()
{


   char *binary = "/path/to/myfiles/program1.ijvm";
   FILE *fp;
   char buffer[32];

   // Open read-only
   fp = fopen(binary, "rb");

   // Read 128 bytes into buffer
   fread (buffer, sizeof(char), 32, fp);



   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: time to check error codes, probably fp is null (BTW activating warnings at compile time would also point you some potential problems...)

Comment: You are reading 32 bytes, not 128

Comment: Please don't repeat in the comment what is written in the code. It leads to what we see here: Comments with literals are almost always wrong. ;-)

Comment: If any of these answer are helpful, please upvote them and/or accept them as the answer. Also, have you figured out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the path. Make sure that `"/path/to/myfiles/program1.ijvm"` points to an existing file.
You should always check the return value of `fopen`.

```
\\Open read-only
fp = fopen(binary, "rb");
if(fp==NULL){
    perror("problem opening the file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Notice also that you are reading 32 bytes in your buffer and not 128 as your comment says.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* check the return result from `fopen()`.

I'm assuming  you are getting the segfault in the `fread()` call because your data file doesn't exist, or couldn't be opened, and you are trying to work on a NULL FILE structure.

See the following safe code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SIZE_BUFFER      32

int main()
{
   char *binary = "data.txt";
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   char buffer[SIZE_BUFFER];

   // Open read-only
   fp = fopen(binary, "rb");

   // Read SIZE_BUFFER bytes into buffer
   if( fp )
   {
        printf("Elements read %ld\n", fread (buffer, sizeof(char), SIZE_BUFFER, fp));
        fclose(fp);
   }
   else
   {
        // Use perror() here to show a text description of what failed and why
        perror("Unable to open file: ");
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

When I execute this code it doesn't crash and will print the number of elements read if the file is opened or it will print "Unable to open file" if the file could not be opened.

As mentioned in the comments you should also close the file being exiting. Another thing you can do is the following:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(.....);
```

Instead of declaring and assigning in two separate steps.

Comment: He should also close the file before returning

Comment: Why must you initialize `fp` to `NULL`? What about things like `FILE *fp = fopen("/foo/bar/baz.quux");`?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Of course, you can do the open and assignment of fp on the same line.

Comment: @Chimera Then why _must_ you set `fp` to NULL? As long as `fp` is _unconditionally_ set to the result of `fopen(3)`, it shouldn't matter what it was initially bound to.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Did you read my answer where I said "Also note, it's a good idea to initialize FILE *fp to NULL. On my machine, if I didn't do that and the file wasn't opened it would still crash."

Comment: `fp` does not need to be initialised. It is set later before being used. This is Ok. If is was being used before being used that would be a problem

Comment: @Chimera, yes but the second sentence of your answer is *Also, you must initialize `fp` to null. The following code is safe.* I am unsure if you are asserting if it is a _must_ or a _should_. Also, I don't understand why it is unsafe to not initialize `fp` when you are immediately assigning it, especially since `man 3 fopen` states clearly that it will only be non-null if it was opened successfully. If you don't use it before assigning it, I don't see how that would be an issue.

Comment: @EdHeal That is what you would think. However. on my machine and compiler, if I don't initialize fp to null the program fails if the file isn't opened.

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Ok, it's a should.

Comment: It's good practice to initialize all of your variables when you declare them, regardless.

Comment: Thought experiment `FILE *fp;` - `fp` can be anything. Program continues. Next time `fp` is used is here `fp = fopen....` - Now `fp` has a value. After this things are dangy is the value of `fp` is treated properly

Comment: @EdHeal YES! That is how it *should* work. But that isn't what my compiler / std library DID.

Comment: Sorry but this statement `Also note, it's a good idea to initialize FILE *fp to NULL. On my machine, if I didn't do that and the file wasn't opened it would still crash.` is untrue.`fp` will be set to `NULL` in the event of not being able to open the file - as per the manual,

Comment: @EdHeal Would  you like to see how my compiler/library failed that though experiment? I can show you.

Comment: @EdHeal I just redid my test. I must tested incorrectly. I just updated my answer. I thought it was weird that I'd have to initialize fp. I don't know how I ran a bad test. :-(

Comment: @Chimera - No worries - It happens to the best of us

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons

1. The `fopen(3)` function failed due to some reason, which means `fp` is NULL, and then you are trying to use the null-pointer in `fread(3)`. This can crash. @OznOg has already given a subtle hint to look into this direction.
2. If the `fopen` call is a success (i.e. `fp` is non-NULL after calling `fopen`), the code can still crash because you are reading 32 chars into the variable `binary`, while `binary` has been initialized with only 30 chars.

Comment: But he has `char binary[32]` declared, not `binary[30]`

Comment: The buffer size is NOT the problem. It's exactly the size of the number of bytes being read. Most certainly the issue is the file isn't being open leaving fp null.

Comment: thanks EdwardMinnix and Chimera for your comments. He edited his code after I posted my comments, hence this discrepancy or confusion. Earlier it was something like 'char *buffer = "/path/to/myfiles/program1.ijvm" which is also mentioned in the other answer to this question by gerardo